# Retrieving display value of lookup field in Dynamics CRM C# plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, lookup, dynamics-crm-4

I am trying to retrieve the display value of a lookup field in a plugin for MS Dynamics CRM 4.0. The value of the attribute is a GUID which points to another entity (owner of salesorder in this case). "Normal" attributes I retrieve with a code like this:

```
CrmDateTime  serviceOrderDateDT = (CrmDateTime)entity["submitdate"];
                      serviceOrderDate = serviceOrderDateDT.Value.ToString();
```

Any ideas on how to do this for the display value of a lookup field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Owner ownerLookup = (Owner)entity["ownerid"];
string ownerName = ownerLookup.name;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I do this I get : "the given key was not present in the dictionairy". My salesorder does have a owner offcourse! Any ideas?

Comment: You need to make sure ownerid is in your column set when you retrieve the entity.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to cast that property to type Owner not Lookup, i.e.:

```
(Owner)entity["ownerid"]
```